# About an assumption for a function F that is increasing and right continuous

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove something in my measure theory homework and I just had a quick question about an assumtion we need to make about a function $F$ that is increasing and right continuous. I want to know why I can assume $F(a)<\infty$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. It's because $F$ is right continuous, correct? I mean, if $F(a)$ were infinite, we wouldn't be able to determine a right or even a left limit for that matter. If I'm wrong, I'm sorry for being silly. Thanks for your help ahead of time.

Ok, quick, but very important edit. $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So $F(a)< \infty$ because $F$ maps to the reals, right?

Comment: Do you mean $F(a) < \infty$?

Comment: More context is needed to answer with certainty.  It makes sense to use $[-\infty,\infty]$ with its order topology as the codomain of a function, and there are then increasing continuous functions that take $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as values and even the function that is always $+\infty$ is an example.  This could be ruled out in context.  For example, is the result you're trying to prove trivial when $F\equiv +\infty$?  If so, then the assumption is just to move on to the interesting stuff.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I made the correction, thank you.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I'm sorry, you're absolutely correct. $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

$F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ means that for every $x\in\mathbb R$, $F(x)$ is in $\mathbb R$.  The set of real numbers does not contain $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry, I was being quite silly. Thank you.